# Cloud functions Error: function crashed out of request scope Function invocation was interrupted

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I randomly get this error message when trying to send notification payloads to some devices.
It will happen maybe 1 in every 10 successful attempts.

I am a complete novice when it comes to cloud functions and node.js, Hoping its a silly simple mistake in my code that only sometimes seems to break.

When searching this error message i find that its maybe down to function completing before the notification even sends. But i am unsure how to go about trying to fix it.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction with the following function...

```
    *** // // --------------------- new chat message function -------------------
  //
  exports.newChatMessage = functions.firestore
  .document('/notifications/{toUID}/newMessage/{docID}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

  const toUser = context.params.toUID;
  const documentID = context.params.docID;
  const newValue = snap.data();
  const title = newValue.title;
  const content = newValue.content;
  const fromUID = newValue.senderUID;
  const senderFirstName = newValue.senderFirstName;
  const deviceToken = newValue.deviceToken;
  const senderThumbUrl = newValue.senderThumbUrl;
  const bigPictureUrl = newValue.bigPictureUrl;
  const messageType = newValue.messageType;
  const time = newValue.time_stamp;

  console.log('New chat message to : ', toUser);
  console.log('Message ID : ', documentID);
  console.log('Type : ', messageType);
  console.log('Message : ', content);
  console.log('Time Stamp : ', time);


  const payload = {
    data : {
      title : title,
      content : content,
      senderUID : fromUID,
      senderThumbUrl : senderThumbUrl,
      senderFirstName : senderFirstName,
      bigPictureUrl : bigPictureUrl,
      messageType : messageType,
      notificationType : 'newChatMessage'
    }
  };

  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken, payload).then(response => {
  console.log('Notification sent successfully');

  const deleteDoc = db.doc(`notifications/${toUser}/newMessage/${documentID}`);
  deleteDoc.delete();
  console.log('Notification document deleted');

  return true;
  })
  .catch(err => {
  console.log('Error : Problem sending notification', err);
  return false;
  });
  return true;
  });
  //
  // // ----------------- END OF :  new chat message function -------------- ***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete.  [This is required by Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).  Not returning a promise means your function is cleaning up before the work is done.  What you should do instead is return the promise chain that you started:

```
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(...).then(...).catch(...)
```

You also need to return the promise returned by `deleteDoc.delete()` from the inner callback, not `return true`.

It's definitely **critical** to understand how to handle JavaScript promises correctly in Cloud Functions, so I suggest studying up on how they work if you are going to keep using it, especially for more complicated tasks.

Comment: Thank you for your quick in depth reply, the link is also really helpful as i think i am starting to understand it now.